# cap deploy upload via sftp failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, web-deployment

Good day! I'll try to be very specific with this. I'm sorry, but I've had experience a lot of troubles while trying to deploy my application. I'm totally new at rails, so I followed the Agile Web Development with Rails 4th Edition and I'm trapped on the segment of deploy with capistrano I've tried the exact code on the book, didn't work, and take some advices from this and others forums that prove to be helpful, but I'm still can't deploy correctly my deploy.rb goes like this:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :user, 'user_created_for_this_example'

set :domain,  'IPADDRESS'

set :application, 'depot'

# file paths

set :repository,  "#{user}@#{domain}:depot.git"

set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{domain}"

# set :scm, :git # You can set :scm explicitly or Capistrano will make an intelligent guess 
based on known version control directory names

# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

#roles server

role :web, domain

role :app, domain

role :db, domain, :primary => true

#deploy config

set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{domain}"

set :deploy_via, :copy

set :scm, 'git'

set :branch, 'master'

set :scm_verbose, true

set :use_sudo, false 


# if you want to clean up old releases on each deploy uncomment this:
# after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:

namespace :deploy do

  task :start do ; end

  task :stop do ; end

  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do

    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"

  end

end

after "deploy:update_code", :bundle_install

desc "install the necesary prerequisites"

task :bundle_install, :roles => :app do

  run "cd #{release_path} && bundle install"

end
```

When i run the cap deploy:setup and cap deploy:check all seems to be working fine:

```
~/rails_projects/depot$ cap deploy:setup

  * 2012-11-13 10:37:35 executing `deploy:setup'

  * executing "mkdir -p /home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx /home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx/releases /home/git
/xx.xx.xx.xx/shared /home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx/shared/system /home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx/shared/log 
/home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx/shared/pids"

    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xx"]

    [xx.xx.xx.xx] executing command

    command finished in 158ms

  * executing "chmod g+w /home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx /home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx/releases /home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx/shared /home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx/shared/system /home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx/shared/log /home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx/shared/pids"

    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xx"]

    [xx.xx.xx.xx] executing command

    command finished in 7ms

~/rails_projects/depot$ cap deploy:check

  * 2012-11-13 10:37:39 executing `deploy:check'

  * executing "test -d /home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx/releases"

    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xx"]

    [xx.xx.xx.xx] executing command

    command finished in 152ms

  * executing "test -w /home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx"

    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xx"]

    [xx.xx.xx.xx] executing command

    command finished in 5ms

  * executing "test -w /home/git/xx.xx.xx.xx/releases"

    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xx"]

    [xx.xx.xx.xx] executing command

    command finished in 5ms

  * executing "which tar"

    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xx"]

    [xx.xx.xx.xx] executing command

    command finished in 6ms

You appear to have all necessary dependencies installed
```

But when the cap deploy:migrations, cap deploy or cap deploy:cold command comes the next pops up:

```
~/rails_projects/depot$ cap deploy:migrations

  * 2012-11-13 10:37:42 executing `deploy:migrations'

  * 2012-11-13 10:37:42 executing `deploy:update_code'

    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@xx.xx.xx.xx:depot.git master"

    command finished in 241ms

  * getting (via checkout) revision c3f88ca97e5868dd476f20e9a044b7dad800274a to /tmp/20121113173743

    executing locally: git clone git@xx.xx.xx.xx:depot.git /tmp/20121113173743 && cd /tmp/20121113173743 && git checkout -b deploy c3f8
8ca97e5868dd476f20e9a044b7dad800274a

Cloning into '/tmp/20121113173743'...

remote: Counting objects: 392, done.

remote: Compressing objects: 100% (257/257), done.

remote: Total 392 (delta 111), reused 392 (delta 111)

Receiving objects: 100% (392/392), 8.59 MiB, done.

Resolving deltas: 100% (111/111), done.

Switched to a new branch 'deploy'

    command finished in 769ms

  * Compressing /tmp/20121113173743 to /tmp/20121113173743.tar.gz

    executing locally: tar czf 20121113173743.tar.gz 20121113173743

    command finished in 652ms

    servers: ["xx.xx.xx.xx"]

 ** sftp upload /tmp/20121113173743.tar.gz -> /tmp/20121113173743.tar.gz

    [xx.xx.xx.xx] /tmp/20121113173743.tar.gz

*** upload via sftp failed on xx.xx.xx.xx: Net::SFTP::StatusException 
(Net::SFTP::StatusException open /tmp/20121113173743.tar.gz (3, "permission denied"))

upload via sftp failed on xx.xx.xx.xx: Net::SFTP::StatusException (Net::SFTP::StatusException open /tmp/20121113173743.tar.gz (3, "permission denied"))
```

I'm sorry if this is some dummy issue, an easy-fix or an already posted one, but I don't know what else to try, again I'm just starting with this stuff and I'm truly lost. I'm running all from the same machine and all the xx.xx.xx.xx stands for my ip address. Any suggestions will be really appreciated. I've tried to be specific as possible, but if something is missing I'll post it. Thanks beforehand for your time and help.

Comment: `permission denied`: Insuficient permissions? Can you access your FTP by hand and write things in `/home/user/etc`?

Comment: I do believe that the issue is in your FTP configuration.

Comment: had the same issue and solve it. With ***ls -al /*** you can see what group is the creator of the tmp folder. With commands id, groups and usermod you must add yourself into creator group.

Comment: This is an old question but this guide may help if you're still wondering: https://help.github.com/articles/deploying-with-capistrano

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that your source and destination locations for sftp are the same:

```
** sftp upload /tmp/20121113173743.tar.gz -> /tmp/20121113173743.tar.gz
```

in order to fix the issue you may specify parameter copy_dir in your config/deploy.rb file, something like this:

```
set :copy_dir, "/tmp/sftp"
```

no need to create that folder manually then.

Comment: Thank you this helped me.  Now shows: sftp upload /tmp/sftp/20160202184928.tar.gz -> /tmp/20160202184928.tar.gz
No more errors

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your deploy.rb configuration file:

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

Comment: Thanks Dario!, but the outcome is still the same, I've also read about adding ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true, with no different results. I do think that the problems are the permissions but I have no idea how o fix that. Again thank you for your answers and time, any suggestion will be taken and sorry for the troubles.

Answer (score 0):

We changed the Capfile from

```
set :deploy_via, :copy
```

to

```
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
```

and this worked for us. We did not add the below line

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```